# how extends the input field until at div end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my bootstrap/html code:

```
  <div class="col-md-8">
   <label for="label_test_email">Put email</label>
   <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="test_email" name="test_email" />
 </div>
```

the position is correct but I want that the size of input field extends until the div end. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the width in percentage like this :

```
#label_test_email{
  width:10%;
}
#test_email{
  width:90%;
}
```

Here is the working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/funuh3Lr/)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to validate you html then defiantly this will give an error. According to W3C, every lavel should refer to any element. Means, the value in the "for" attribute must refer to the  input in you HTML. Hence the Id for input should be same w.r.t value in "for" like below,

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <label for="test_email">Put email</label>
   <input type="text"  class="form-controll" id="test_email" name="test_email" />
```

For full width of input field you can use 100% width,

```
#test_email{
   width: 100%;
}
```

This will automaticaly give you the width of input w.r.t parent div with class "col-md-8"